# Are questions inquiring about the existance of particular inventions\tools in scope here\elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was particularly looking to ask a question about whether devices\methods have been developed to aid urban core fire departments to speed the sluggish, grueling ascent in skyscrapers when existing elevators are truly dangerous, such as was the case on September 11th.  Are inquiries into such technological existence on topic here (or at another SE site)??

Comment: Good question, and I've closed your question against our canonical question on the matter.  The TL;DR is that they are not welcome.  But there's a number of reasons explaining why.

Comment: A pity.  Any suggestions as to a better place for it?

Comment: Or any thoughts on how to improve this question to fit within the confines?  If I narrowed the question to one possible method such as "Would a pulley system along the outside of a building be a feasible method to help firefighters more quickly reach high floors in burning skyscrapers with disabled elevators"?  Hate narrowing it, as I'd be interested in any avenues of consideration... and feel the answers would be too particular to be useful\interesting to many... and still uncertain whether the updated question would meet policy.  Any advice in direction is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Even with your proposed narrower question, it sounds like you're looking for a discussion as opposed to having a specific, answerable question.  A reasonable rule of thumb is that if you need a book or a chapter from a book to properly address a question, then it's going to be too broad for StackExchange.  SE Chat is meant for those types of discussions.  That said, this [site's chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works) tends to be low volume.